# Link two destination objects in FME

Tags: fme-form, relationship-class

I have an object 'building' which is represented into multiple feature classes (point, line ) in esri file geodatabase. Is there a way to copy an attribute in one class to an attribute of another class **with FME**

please have a look at the example below. I have drawn a red arrow indicating the attribute to be copied. Is it possible ? How ?

[image]

Comment: put an attributeRenamer after your attributeCreator Rename BAUTEIL_REF to objectid (check it is numeric)

Comment: There is a video from Safe Software available check geodb_type http://blog.safe.com/2012/03/fmeevangelist100/